# Combining list of 2D numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, concatenation

How do I combine `N`, 2D numpy arrays (of dimension `R x C`) to create a 3D numpy array of shape `(N, R, C)`? Right now, the N-2D numpy arrays are contained inside a list, and I want that to become a 3D numpy array. Let's say `X` is my list of 2D numpy arrays, if I just do `np.array(X)`, I get something of shape `(N,)`. If I do `np.vstack(X)`, I get something of shape `(N x R, C)`. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: If `np.array(X)` does not give you a 3d array, I suspect one of more of the 2d arrays differs in size.  You might try `np.stack(X)`, but it too expects the shapes to match.  If they just differ in the R shape, `vstack` should work, but the `N*R` dimension is doubtful.  You could though reshape the `vstack` result.

Comment: Thanks the issue was indeed that. Once I fixed that issue, I was good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [np.stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html):

```py
test = np.stack([np.ones([2, 3]) for _ in range(4)]) 
print(test.shape) # (4, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just use :

```
np.array([np.array(x) for x in ArrayList])
```

Comment: If `2DarrayList` is already a list of numpy arrays, you don't need the list comp. Note: `2DarrayList` is not a valid variable name